# Adding line breaks to a Python string that will be assigned to a variable rather than "print()"

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on a shopping list script that will input food items entered by the user into a dictionary. The script then converts those items into a string, formats the string for readability, then sends an SMS to another user via Twilio API.

Everything seems to be working perfectly, except the string displays each item on the same line. I've done a search for my specific problem and, while I've seen other questions that talk about printing each element on a string to a new line, that solution does not work when I'm assigning the string to variable, which I need to do in order for Twilio to work as intended. I'd still consider myself very new to Python, so if anyone is able to help, it would be appreciated!

Here is the source (the 'if select == 2' section is commented out as it's not a focus I have at this time. Please disregard it):

```
Shoplist = {} #sets the initial empty dictionary
...
food, quantity = input("Enter the food followed by a space and the 
quantity, or type 'q q' to quit").split(); quantity
Listadd = {food: quantity} #adds the food and quantity of the food into 
a holding dictionary, Listadd
Shoplist.update(Listadd) #updates Shoplist dictionary
 for k, v in Shoplist.items(): #Concatenates dictionary into strings 
for ease of reading
    print(str(k) + ', ' + str(v)) #Shows user an updated shopping 
list
...
        Shoplist = str(Shoplist).replace("
{","").replace("}","").replace(":",",").replace("\'","")
        print(Shoplist)
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Why don't you just add the newlines to the strings? Also, please construct a [mcve] (with a focus on *minimal*), as I doubt you it requires over 30 lines to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Any methods of adding new lines to my strings didn't work and returned various errors since we're adding user-inputted items into a dictionary, then converting that dictionary into a string. I know how to line break and my code works when you simply print the string with breaks, but it no longer works when I assign it to a variable.

Comment: "didn't work" and "returned various errors" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to all this, so I appreciate your guidance and patience with me. Specifically, I've been trying to add a "\n" line break to converted string itself. I believe this line specifically is the issue:
            Shoplist = str(Shoplist).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace(":",",").replace("\'","")

If I use print() instead of assigning the str to the variable Shoplist, '\n' works for a line break. I'm not sure how to work in a \n into the concatenation that I've posted above as any attempt resulted in the characters \n literally being printed.

Answer (score 0):

From the Twilio [documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181468-How-do-I-add-a-line-break-in-my-SMS-message-):

> For sending outbound SMS messages via the REST API, it is best to
> encode a new line as %0a.

With their example being:

`Here+is+my+first+line%0aHere+is+my+second+line`

Sounds like your mistake is in formatting the string for readability. You need to format it to the specification of the API.

Comment: Yes, that was my problem exactly. Thank you so much for your help!